# How static behavior changes?

Tags: java, static

I have searched the forum and found various options for Static and normal variable. But i am still not able to figure out this: -

When i am executing this program given below, i am getting the desired output, but if i delete the "static" key word which is in front of String college, it also gives me the same output.

```
 static String college ="ITS"; // Same output
 String college ="ITS";// Same output
```

So whats the use of using the static keyword??

```
class Student{  
   int rollno;  
   String name;  
      static String college ="ITS";  


Student(int r,String n){  
   rollno = r;  
   name = n;  
   }  
 void display (){System.out.println(rollno+" "+name+" "+college);}  

 public static void main(String args[]){  
 Student s1 = new Student (111,"Karan");  
 Student s2 = new Student (222,"Aryan");  

 s1.display();  
 s2.display();  
 }  
}
```

Comment: @hexafraction I tried to reword the question as i was not getting the right answer anywhere. So could u take a minute to explain this small query.

Comment: @hexafraction: please help.